issue regarding a character face(with a different face texture) shading unexpectedly
The issue I'm having is that I have 2 materials applied to the body of a low-poly character I'm modelling. One of these materials has just been texture painted on and is the skin/underclothes color, and the other is a 2D drawn face that can swap between some expressions with shader nodes

despite the skin tone of the both being the same color(as per the hex code used to paint both), they're differently shaded in the viewports. Lighting doesn't seem to have any effect, as even in renderview, the outlines of the areas where the face texture has been applied remain as clear as the material preview. I dont know what other information is relevant to give an answer to this, But I don't know how to fix it myself

Hard to tell without further infos: do colors match in the 2D image textures? Do the Image texture nodes share the same Color space? Did you paint with full power of the brush? Are face normals correct? Maybe you could pack external data and share your file.

the colors do match in the 2D image textures, but both textures have different shader node setups, so they wouldnt share the same nodes. Brush was at full strength, and as far as correcting the face normals if they're messed up....I wouldn't really know how to do that.
https://mega.nz/file/euBCRJxJ#PRY5xmU-ZM8oImlzEeighB_fSv15uDi7Bjvfc4XyS1U is a packed file of the model

The Fbx doesn't contain the textures. You can go to File Menu > Exernal Data > Pack Resources, then directly upload the Blender file.

whoops, heres the blend file. https://mega.nz/file/e2h10JRa#pi65nCvp-ohnDJWpr6gZCS0QA6ik_JoNGOCdOdApvbs

The body material uses Principled BSDF Shader, while the Face material uses an Emission Shader.
In order to have continuity you have to use only one of them for both materials:
to solve, go to object mode, select the Face material, go to Shader editor window, delete the Emission node, go to menu > Add > Shader > Principled BSDF, and plug Color to Base Color Input, and BSDF to Surface Output.


Oh, thanks a bunch! Didn't know there was a distinction like that.
